# Filter queue overview in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there a way to filter the visible queues within the ActiveMQ queue overview?
We have a lot of different queues and thus the overview page is very full. It would be great to filter away not so important queues by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the web admin console configuration, then No - it's not built to scale with a lot of queues.

But then again, the console is a simple java web app , so you could easily implement a filter yourself if you really need it.

The most quick n dirty way I can think of is open `webapps/admin/queues.jsp` and add an JSP-if statement in the forEach-loop. It will be very hard coded, but is very quick and does not even require a server restart, just a simple browser reload.

```
<c:forEach items="${requestContext.brokerQuery.queues}" var="row">

<!-- Only show queues starting with Important. -->
<c:if test="${fn:startsWith(row.name,'Important.')}">
.. 
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

There are, of course, much more sophisticated and better ways to achieve this if you're up to the task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know a good alternative to the web admin console?

Comment: There is hawt.io, but it's even worse with large amount of queues (good in other ways though). For some tasks, such as sending test messages etc,  I prefer a command line tool called A (https://github.com/fmtn/a  - written by me).